# Jquery dropdown off navbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following dropdown code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropbtn").hover(function(){
        $(".dropdown-content").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $(".dropdown").mouseout(function(){
        $(".dropdown-content").slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">##</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">##</a>
    <a href="#">##</a>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

But when I hover over the dropdown-content, it contracts, as if dropdown-content is not a part of the li class "dropdown" out of which the slideup is triggered in jquery. How can I make it so that the dropdown-content only slides up when the mouse leaves the nav element or dropdown content?

Comment: I see you put wrong event binding name there, try change `.hover(` to `.mouseenter(` and change `.mouseout(` to `.mouseleave(` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a container, you can ensure the events only fire in relation to the whole item. In addition, use mouseleave to prevent the child elements from firing the event as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").mouseover(function() {
    $(".dropdown-content").slideDown("fast");
  });
  $(".container").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".dropdown-content").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">##</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">##</a>
        <a href="#">##</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was because I didn't have jquery included to the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you had that in your html.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this line to the button of the page. It works.